# Making pointer to const object from pointer typedef

Tags: c++, type-traits

Imagine a situation

```
struct Foo{};

typedef Foo* FooPtr;
```

when we have access only to `FooPtr` not Foo (for example class defines such public typedef)

Then we want to make container of `const Foo pointers`. Not container of `const pointers to Foo objects` (which is forbidden)

So I can't do

```
std::vector<const FooPtr> v;    
//gives
//std::vector<Foo * const, std::allocator<Foo * const> >
```

What C++ offers for this situations? 
(I know it is more design issue, class Foo should offers better typedef, or it is not intended to use it like I want)

The only solution I came up with is

```
std::vector<const std::remove_pointer<FooPtr>::type *> vv; 
//gives
//std::vector<Foo const *, std::allocator<Foo const *> >
```

or more nicely written (and very poorly named (any name suggestions?)) as trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct add_const_ignore_ptr
{
    typedef typename const std::remove_pointer<T>::type * type;
};
```

used like

```
typedef add_const_ignore_ptr<FooPtr>::type ConstFooPtr;

std::vector<ConstFooPtr> vvv;
```

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore the given typedef, do a forward declaration for Foo and define an own typedef.

```
struct Foo;

using MyConstFooPtr = const Foo*;

std::vector<MyConstFooPtr> myVec;
```

**edit:**
As Simon stated out, another solution is necessary. You could exploit 'decltype' to deduce the type information you need:

```
//
class Test
{
    private:
        struct Foo { int a; }; 

    public:
        typedef Foo* FooPtr;
};

//
template<typename T>
const T* toConst(T);

//
int main()
{
    std::vector<decltype(toConst(*Test::FooPtr()))> myVec;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quote: _when we have access only to FooPtr not Foo (for example class defines such public typedef)_ So if you have something like this `class Test
{
private:
 struct Foo { int a; };
public:
 typedef Foo* FooPtr;
};` your solution won't work.